# Case insensitive Rspec match

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, case-insensitive

I'm writing a Capybara test and using Rspec for the assertions. My test is failing because there is a CSS style being applied that is causing the text to be in all caps. How can I rewrite this so that it is a case insensitive assertion?

```
"ALL CAPS".should include('All Caps')
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here's improving on phoet's solution:

```rb
page.body.should match(%r{#{string}}i)
```

Unfortunately the syntax highlighting here isn't doing it much justice (it looks perfectly fine in Sublime Text)

Comment: This also works in Capybara finders. For example:

`page.find 'li.line-item', text: %r{Awesome Line Item}i`

Comment: or `page.find 'li.line-item', text: /#{Awesome Line Item}/i` if you prefer the slash syntax. (Add parentheses around the regex in Sublime Text to get proper syntax highlighting.)

Answer (score 7):

I only run into this issue when:

- Using poltergeist driver. (I don't know if this also happens with other drivers)
- Inspecting `page`, not `page.body` for expectations: `expect(page).to ...`

So, If I do `expect(page.body).to ...` it just works and solved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

how about using a regex to do this?

```
"ALL CAPS".should match(/#{Regexp.escape('All Caps')}/i)
```

Answer (score 6):

How about downcasing both ends of the assertion?

```
"ALL CAPS".downcase.should include('All Caps'.downcase)
```

Comment: this solution was actually the most versatile across different matcher scenarios I ran into. Even though it's kind of ugly, it works

Comment: you could abstract it out to a custom method if you want to hide a bit of the uglyness heh

Answer (score 6):

Rspec syntax has changed significantly in 4 years, but this underlying problem still seems like a problem. My solution was to build a custom matcher `has_content_i`, which was like `has_content` but is case insensitive. The resulting call looks like:

```
expect(page).to have_content_i("All Caps")
```

Here's the source:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_content_i do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    actual.text =~ /#{Regexp.quote expected}/i
  end

  failure_message do |actual|
     "expected to find text #{expected.inspect} case insensitively in #{actual.text.inspect}"
  end

  failure_message_when_negated do |actual|
    "expected to not to find text #{expected.inspect} case insensitively in #{actual.text.inspect}"
  end
end
```

http://danielchangnyc.github.io/blog/2014/01/15/tdd2-RSpecMatchers/ has information on where to stash the custom matcher definitions in your project tree.

Answer (score 3):

Also, if you are using Capybara, <strike>you can use the `have_content` matcher which is case insensitive:</strike>

```
<h1>ALL CAPS</h1>

find('h1').should have_content('All Caps')
```

**Update:** I guess I was partly wrong. Consider this:

```
<h1 style="text-transform: uppercase">Title Case</h1>

puts find('h1').text
# TITLE CASE  < notice all caps

puts find('h1').has_content?('Title Case')  # true

puts find('h1').has_content?('TITLE CASE')  # false

puts find('h1').has_content?('title case')  # false
```

It's strange to me that the text returned is in all caps (how it's styled after CSS), but the matcher is actually testing against the text in the unstyled HTML. I spent a while digging through the source code and I still can't figure out why this works.

Comment: which version of Capybara is this? I don't remember Capybara having matchers that are case insensitive by default

Comment: do you happen to be using webrat as well?

Comment: hmm, I would suggest you do a check with `puts find('h1').text` and/or `puts find('h1').inspect` to see what exactly is being found. On my end I get back 'ALL CAPS' which rightly fails in your example.

Comment: That's really strange, did you manage to find out, why it has this behaviour?

Comment: it's been a long time since I've looked at it, but I don't think I ever figured it out