# Make Poltergeist case insensitive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, poltergeist

I'm using [Poltergeist](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist) / [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) for my tests:

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {
      timeout: 60,
      phantomjs_options: ['--load-images=no'],
      case_insensitive: true # <-- doesn't work
    })
  end
end
```

but I noticed that I have to rewrite a lot of tests, as Poltergeists driver seems to be `case-sensitive`. Is there anything I can pass to change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @eugen mentions all searches in capybara are case sensitive by default.  The problem you mention of having to rewrite tests usually occurs when moving from a driver that does/does-not support css text-transform to one that does-not/does - so the text being matched is or is not having the css text-transform (uppercase/lowercase/capitalize/...) applied. If you want to be able to swap back and forth between drivers and really need case insensitivity you can pass regexes to the different matchers

```
expect(page).to have_text(/case insensitive text/i)
expect(page).to have_selector(:css, '#div1', text: /case insensitive text/i)
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense. My driver before was case insensitive. However, I would like to use `expect(page).to have_content` instead of `have_text`. Is this working fine with your answer?

Comment: Indeed! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex when comparing strings

```
expect(page.body).to match(%r{#{string}}i)
```

source: [Case insensitive Rspec match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316249/case-insensitive-rspec-match)

Answer (score 1):

All searches in `capybara` are case sensitive, there is no global option to change that. If you need to do case insensitive matching, you'll have to do it on a search by search basis.